# Will nighttime always be dangerous?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

I'm not too far in the game yet, so traveling at nighttime is pretty scary, since high level daemons come out and absolutely destroy my party members who don't understand the concept of fleeing (looking at you, *Prompto*). I'm curious if this will always be the case or not. I've noticed that some of the daemons were only in their 30s. For me, that's really strong, but I believe the level cap is 99. Therefore, when I'm further in the game, will the nighttime daemons continue to scale up in levels so that they're always stronger than me? Or will I eventually be on equal ground with them?

Comment: I imagine that like other Final Fantasy games with a similar style (FF12 for example), once you level up to a certain spot, enemies will become more equal to your skill. I haven't yet played FF15 though, so I can't say for sure.

Comment: I won't answer definitively, since I haven't had time to play very far, but according to the Piggyback strategy guide, in the primer section, the nighttime worry is something for the beginning of the game, and lessens as you progress.  It does, however, remind you, frequently, to do as many side quests as you can to stay ahead of the leveling curve.  :)

Comment: I've never had a problem avoiding daemons by sprinting as soon as I hear them pop up, and I've run around at night since level 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question is subjective based on your play style and "ability" to play the game. Daemon fights are built to be more difficult than daytime fights. A person's knowledge of the combat system and how to use their equipment becomes increasingly more important as the game goes on. However I can answer some direct points.

**Will nighttime always be dangerous?**

<s>Yes, nighttime will always be a decently dangerous undertaking. It will always be more dangerous than day time. During the main story, the daemons become both stronger and greater in numbers. As your level up, and more importantly, spend your Ability Points, your party becomes drastically better at being able to handle the daemons however, so it becomes less of a problem than at the beginning of the game, by quite a large amount.</s>

**UPDATE: NO** It appears the demons at night stay around the same level throughout the game. (Exception being the endgame chapter where its always night.) Even while in chapter 15 and im level 99, the demons still seem to be mostly around the mid 30's. There may be some unique exceptions, but I havent run into any.

Also, as is mentioned in the comments, you can unlock a set of headlights for the Regalia that lets you drive at night without running into any daemons.

**Will the nighttime daemons continue to scale up in levels so that they're always stronger than me? Or will I eventually be on equal ground with them?**

No, the daemons will not always be higher level than you. <s>They tend to be higher level than the beasts during the day based on the chapter your on, but if you complete enough sidequests you can out level the daemons.</s>

Comment: Also worth noting that you eventually get headlights for your car that recent daemon encounters while driving.